# nginx + symfony 404 on static files (macos)

Tags: nginx

symfony 4.3

my local nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name test.local;
    root /Users/user/Documents/Project/test/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

}
```

Php files start correctly, but all static = 404 error

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing some instructions in your block.

Here is a suggestion:

```
server {
    server_name test.local;
    root /Users/user/Documents/Project/test/public;

    # You should add an index to specify to Nginx which file should be served.
    index index.php

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
    rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        # Here too you should specify your index file
        index index.php;
        # Change also this line.
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    # Add this block too to replace index.php in the URL
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # I usually set this up:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root; # I'm not sure if you need this.
        # I also usually set a timeout:
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks! But I get "invalid variable name" error on
`rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;`

Comment: Correct, I forgot to edit this line `try_files $uri @rewriteapp;` in `location /`. Is it better now? You can also try to comment this line to see how your app behaves...

Comment: no, this config also rerurn 404 for all static(
can this be due to violation of any access rights?
thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you tell me where your static files are located?

Comment: shure,
/Users/user/Documents/Project/PROJECT_DIR/public/*

Comment: Ok, that's weird. I can't say why you've got this 404 error, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me:

I add this blocks:

```
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|ico|swf|flv|pdf|zip)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite $uri $uri;
    }
```

after that, static files give 403 error

and I add my user to /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user username staff;

And after this - it works for me